# achartengine - timechart or linechart?

Tags: time, charts, achartengine, linechart

I would like to visualize with aChartEngine a series of measurements. For this I have double values ​​in which to compare the results and are currently still a string with time. Currently I use a line graph with the results and the number. I would now replace by the time the number. Unfortunately, I do not know how and find no suitable examples.

**Edit**
Okay, have found a good example and its work. But how i can make it flexible like the normal label?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty examples of using the AChartEngine APIs in the official demo application. See [these](http://www.achartengine.org/content/goodies.html) instructions in order to figure out how to download the demo source code.